# Turning List<DateTime> into Lists that have them separated per same month and year

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I currently have `billDates`, a list of dates that are very inconsistent. What I want to do is have separate lists or arrays of the dates by month. I.e. if I have `12/30/2015`, `1/5/2016`, `1/6/2016`, `2/5/2016`, I should have 3 lists.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// billDates = list of DateTime
List<List<DateTime>> datesByMonth = new List<List<DateTime>>();
var years = billDates.GroupBy(x => x.Year);

foreach (var year in years)
{
    var months = year.GroupBy(x => x.Month);
    foreach (var month in months)
    {
        List<DateTime> datesWithinMonth = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (DateTime dt in month)
        {
            datesWithinMonth.Add(dt);
        }
        datesByMonth.Add(datesWithinMonth);
    }
}
```

My results have them separated, but they all have them grouped incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ordering by year/month before you iterate over them may fix your ordering issue.

Comment: `billDates.GroupBy(x => x.Year*12+x.Month);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try grouping your list by Month and Year properties, for sample:

```
var groupResult = billDates.GroupBy(x => new { x.Month, x.Year });

List<List<DateTime>> datesByMonth = groupResult.Select(g => g.ToList())
                                               .ToList();
```

You have to select each group on the `groupResult` with the `Select` method and make it as a list. Finally, just take all the lists with `ToList` method and get a list of lists (of datetime in your case).

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for the help. Could you possible elaborate on how this would turn into separate lists from groupResult? EDIT: haha, never mind you already edited for that. thanks!

Comment: You can iterate over groupResult to get each single List<DateTime> that was returned by GroupBy-method

Comment: I've corrected it. Actually, you have to select the group result with the `Select` method and make it as a list. Finally, just get a list with `ToList` method.

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks for the help.